# ios swift - functions causes indexing to take forever and not build

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

Hopefully someone has an answer for this.

I spent hours figuring out why xcode took forever compiling and why it was stuck at building/indexing. I found out it was because of these two functions:

```
public func setLocationsToSession(view: UIViewController, Completion callback: @escaping (_ status: String) -> Void) {
    getStudentLocations(view: view){(error, data) in
        print("setting session")
        print(data)

        if let results = data!["results"] {
            for student in results as! [AnyObject] {
                // check the object for the required keys/subscripts
                if let objectId = student["objectId"], let uniqueKey = student["uniqueKey"], let fname = student["firstName"], let lname = student["lastName"], let mapString = student["mapString"], let mediaURL = student["mediaURL"], let lat = student["latitude"], let lng = student["longitude"], let createdAt = student["createdAt"], let updatedAt = student["updatedAt"] {
                    // some other students are forgetting to POST/PUT the required key-value pairs in their request(s), 
                    // and it breaks my code/app. So this is why i have all of these optional defaults
                    if(fname as String == "" || lname as String == "" || lat as String == "" || lng as String == "" || lat == 0 || lng == 0) {
                        // ignore the bad ones
                        continue
                    }
                    let newStudent = Student(dict: [
                        "objectId": objectId as? String ?? "",
                        "uniqueKey": uniqueKey as? String ?? "",
                        "firstName": fname as! String,
                        "lastName": lname as! String,
                        "mapString": mapString as? String ?? "",
                        "mediaURL": mediaURL as? String ?? "",
                        "latitude": lat as! Double ?? 0.0,
                        "longitude": lng as? Double ?? 0.0,
                        "createdAt": createdAt as? String ?? "",
                        "updatedAt": updatedAt as? String ?? ""
                        ])
                    session.studentLocations.append(newStudent)
                }
                else {
                    continue
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            let value = keys.error
            callback(value)
        }

        let value = error == true ? keys.error : keys.success
        callback(value)
    }
}

public func getStudentLocation(view: UIViewController, key: String, Completion callback: @escaping (_ Error: Bool) -> Void) {
    var reqDICT: [String: Any] = [String:Any]()

    reqDICT["url"] = "https://parse.udacity.com/parse/classes/StudentLocation?where={\"uniqueKey\":\"\(key)\"}"
    reqDICT["method"] = "GET"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: escapeString(value: reqDICT["url"] as! String))!)
    request.httpMethod = reqDICT["method"] as! String
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("QrX47CA9cyuGewLdsL7o5Eb8iug6Em8ye0dnAbIr", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
    request.addValue("QuWThTdiRmTux3YaDseUSEpUKo7aBYM737yKd4gY", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
    reqDICT["request"] = request

    httpRequest(view: view, requestDICT: reqDICT) {(error, data) in
        print("error: \(error) ; data: \(data)")

        if let results = data!["results"], results.count > 0 {
            print("results exist: \(results.count)")
            let Res = results as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let student = Res[0] as! AnyObject
                print("results: \(results)")
                print("student: \(student)")
                let newStudent = Student(dict: [
                    "objectId": student["objectId"] as? String ?? "",
                    "uniqueKey": student["uniqueKey"] as? String ?? "",
                    "firstName": student["firstName"] as? String ?? "",
                    "lastName": student["lastName"] as? String ?? "",
                    "mapString": student["mapString"] as? String ?? "",
                    "mediaURL": student["mediaURL"] as? String ?? "",
                    "latitude": student["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0,
                    "longitude": student["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0,
                    "createdAt": student["createdAt"] as? String ?? "",
                    "updatedAt": student["updatedAt"] as? String ?? ""
                    ])
                session.you = newStudent
                session.objID = student["objectId"] as! String
                session.dataExists = true

        }
        else {
            session.dataExists = false
        }

        callback(error)
    }

}
```

I created these functions to handle the JSON response from an HTTP Request. The problem is that not all of the json objects in the results array have the same keys; some don't have keys that others do. That's why in these two functions I wrote, I tried to unwrap the keys in the JSON object in the `if let` statement and when I'm instantiating a new `struct` to prevent `nil`. That is what is causing xcode to take forever compiling because when I commented those two out, it compiled/build/run in seconds. How else can I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the dictionary literals.  If you want to speed things up, create the dictionary the normal way, then add all the items, eg:

```
var newStudent = [String: String]()
newStudent["objectId"] = student["objectId"] as? String ?? ""
// etc...
```

Comment: ok, so create a dictionary first, THEN pass it to the Struct right? i will try that out. Thanks!

Comment: Also valid to take a look at https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/regarding-swift-build-time-optimizations-fc92cdd91e31 and use the tool mentioned there.